# Get values from database where column is unique

Tags: php, sql, database

I need help with an advanced SQL-query (MSSQL 2000).

I have a table called `Result` that lists athletics 100 meter race-times. A runner can have several racetimes but I want to show only the best time from each runner.

The Result-table contains three columns, `Result_id`, `athlete_id`, `result_time`. So `athlete_id` must be unique when I list the values and `result_time` must be the fastest (lowest) value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply need the fastest time for each `athlete_id`, do this:

```
select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
from result
group by athelete_id
```

To show additional columns from the `result` table, you can join back to it like this:

```
select r.*
from result r
inner join (
    select athelete_id, min(result_time) as FastestTime
    from result
    group by athelete_id
) rm on r.athelete_id = rm.athelete_id and r.result_time = rm.FastestTime
```

Comment: This one is working but how can I include result_date and show result_time? I can only echo athlete_id at the moment

Comment: @Inzajt According to your question, there is no `result_date` column. *"The Result-table contains three columns, Result_id, athlete_id, result_time"*

Comment: Sorry for that, I wanted to make it as easy as possible for you to help me.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000, you can't use windows functions.  You can do this as follows:

```
select r.*
from result r join
     (select athlete_id, min(result_time) as mintime
      from result r
      group by athlete_id
     ) rsum
     on rsum.athlete_id = r.athlete_id and r.time = rsum.mintime
```

In more recent versions of SQL Server, you would use row_number().

Comment: What do you mean by *windows functions* ? And why do a join to the same table when you just want an aggregate function?

Comment: Windows functions are one name for functions that use the "over" staetment (usually followed by "partition by" and/or "order by").  SQL Server 2005 and onwards supports row_number(), rank(), dense_rank(), and ntile() as special functions, in addition to other aggregation functions.

Comment: Cheers for the explanation of windows functions :) Still though, why do a join on itself if he only wants the minimum value of one column? I haven't used SQLServer much at all, but surely the query could be a simple aggregate instead? (I hate to question folk with rep as intimidating as yours, but even the chap with 55K seems to think a simple aggregate would work?)

Comment: Because *I* would want everything else in the results table, such as the date of the event.  For only the minimum time, the other answers are fine.

Comment: I do accually need to show result-date etc. But I could not get this one to work, it still show all result_times.

Comment: I still don't understand. I built this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/575b5/1) to try to understand your code, but it is returning every single row, not just the minimum race times?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank goodness for that, I thought I was seriously losing my marbles :)

Comment: I believe they are more commonly called *window [singular] functions*.  (When I think of "windows" functions I think of `CreateWindowEx` or `xp_cmdshell` or similar.)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use an aggregate function. in this case `min()` which will select the minumin data from all the rows that have the same data in the other selected columns. This means you also have to us the group by clause. The query below should give you the results you want.

Edit: If you need other columns, just bring them into the `select` clause, then add them to the `group by` clause like below:

`select althlete_id, result_id, min(result_time) as result_time from result-table group by althlete_id, result_id`

`select althlete_id, result_id, min(result_time) as result_time, race_date from result-table group by althlete_id, race_date, result_id`

Edit: You need to add all the columns into the `group by` that aren't part of an aggregate function. Aggregate functions are ones like `min()`, `max()`, `avg()` and so on.

Short answer: If you aren't putting a column in brackets, it probably has to be in the group by.

Comment: This works when I remove result_id, but I cant echo out result_time, how can I include that in "group_by"? it already exists in "select" in the MIN() function, wont I mess things up if I add in the "group by"?

Comment: forget what I wrote, I forgot to sort the table, cant get this one to work either. Show all results

Comment: You can name the aggregate function. I am modifying my answer to show.